# jquery- How to automatically insert colon after entering 2 numeric digits

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want a to have a text box which accepts HH:MM(hours/minutes) format. So, when the user enters the value for HH, it should automatically insert a colon after that and let the user enter value for MM.

I do not want to use any plugin for this.

How do i do this?

thanks

Comment: Keep it simple, use one input for hours, another for minutes. Your requirement to not use plugins is a little odd, as there's lots of masking libraries which already do this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HTML:

```
<input class="time" type="text"/><br/>
<input class="time" type="text"/><br/>
<input class="time" type="text"/>
```

JS:

```
var time = document.getElementsByClassName('time'); //Get all elements with class "time"
for (var i = 0; i < time.length; i++) { //Loop trough elements
    time[i].addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {; //Add event listener to every element
        var reg = /[0-9]/;
        if (this.value.length == 2 && reg.test(this.value)) this.value = this.value + ":"; //Add colon if string length > 2 and string is a number 
        if (this.value.length > 5) this.value = this.value.substr(0, this.value.length - 1); //Delete the last digit if string length > 5
    });
};
```

[Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/v4so8otb/1/)

Comment: can we have something using class name and not the id. as i a lot of text boxes with this format and giving a different id to these is not recommended. Not going well when i use class name

Comment: Can I also add any regex for HH:MM format in this code? how do I do that?

Comment: Also, one problem this code has is- when i enter hh value and then try to hit back space on hh value,it automatically appends one more colon.      for ex- if i have typed- 21: and now i hit backspace on digit 1, the output is 2::

Comment: i answered your problem so far. Sorry, you have to refine it by yourself

Comment: Here is the solution for that delete bug in case someone needs it still https://stackoverflow.com/a/45633656/3280918

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple inputs

```
<input class="test-input" placeholder="hh:mm" value=""/>
<input class="test-input" placeholder="hh:mm" value=""/>
<input class="test-input" placeholder="hh:mm" value=""/>
<input class="test-input" placeholder="hh:mm" value=""/>
<input class="test-input" placeholder="hh:mm" value=""/>
```

**Jquery Version:**

```
$(document).on('ready',function(){
      $('.test-input').on('keyup',keyUpHandler);
});


    function keyUpHandler(e){  
        var element = this;
        var key = e.keyCode || e.which;   
        insertTimingColor(element,key)
    }

    function insertTimingColor(element,key){
        var inputValue = element.value;
        if(element.value.trim().length == 2 && key !== 8){
            element.value = element.value + ':';
        }
    }
```

**[fiddle - jquery](https://jsfiddle.net/yrxg4emz/4/)**

**Vanilla JS version**

```
document.body.addEventListener('keyup',keyUpHandler,false);

function keyUpHandler(e){  
    var evt = e || window.event;
    var target = evt.target || evt.srcElement;
    var key = e.keyCode || e.which;   

    //check if it is our required input with class test input
    if(target.className.indexOf('test-input') > -1){
        insertTimingColor(target,key)
    }

}

function insertTimingColor(element,key){
    var inputValue = element.value;
    if(element.value.trim().length == 2 && key !== 8){
        element.value = element.value + ':';
    }
}
```

**[fiddle - js](https://jsfiddle.net/yrxg4emz/5/)**

Comment: This fails for input like 21:3::21:3::21::3:21::

Comment: @RahulTripathi.....the user only asked for adding a colon after we add two digits....this is also possible...

Comment: how do we do it by using class instead of id?

Comment: @Atharva...you can check now.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('id or class or parent id').on('keypress','class or id', function (e){
    var key = e.keyCode || e.which;
            if(this.value.trim().length == 2 && key !==8  && this.value.search
    (':') != -1)
        this.value = this.value + ':';
});

    $('id or class or parent id').on('keyup click','class or id', function (e){

    if(this.value.length >= 3)
        this.selectionStart = this.selectionEnd = this.value.length;

});
$('id or class or parent id').on('paste','class or id', function (e){
    e.preventDefault();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it.

```
jQuery("#textboxId").keypress(function(){
       if(jQuery("#textboxId").val().length)==2{
          var value=jQuery("#textboxId").val();
          jQuery("#textboxId").val(value+":");
       }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id = "timeInput" maxlength = 14>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#timeInput").focusin(function (evt) {
    $(this).keypress(function () {
        content=$(this).val();
        content1 = content.replace(/\:/g, '');
        length=content1.length;
        if(((length % 2) == 0) && length < 10 && length > 1){
            $('#timeInput').val($('#timeInput').val() + ':');
        }
    });
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/r7e0ht3m/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var global_flag = true;
  $("#texboxId").on('keyup', function() {
    var cur_val = $(this).val();
    var cur_length = cur_val.length;
    var flag = true;
    if (cur_length > 5) {
      cur_val = cur_val.substring(0, 5);
      $(this).val(cur_val);
    } else {
      if (cur_length > 2) {
        global_flag = false;
      } else if (global_flag == false && cur_length < 2) {
        global_flag = true;
      }
      if (cur_length == 2 && global_flag) {
        if (window.event.keyCode != 8) {
          $(this).val(cur_val + ":");
        }
      }
      if (cur_length == 5) {
        if (cur_val.match(/^(([0-1][0-9]){0,2}|(2[0-3]){0,2}){0,2}:([0-5][0-9]){0,2}$/)) {} else {
          $(this).val("");
          $(this).attr('placeholder', "HH:MM");

        }
      }

    }

  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below should do the trick for you. Now all you will need to do is add some validation, like only allowing numeric key press values.

```
<input id="time-input" placeholder="hh:mm"  type="text">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#time-input").keypress(function(){
       $this = $(this);       
       if($this.val().length == 2){
           $this.val($this.val() + ":");
       }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g9nahpax/