# Can't delete dynamically added colon

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need a function that will add the colon (:) after you type two numbers in input and I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30093962/3280918) here on StackOverflow as well which is what I need. It add colon after typed second number and won't let u add more than 4 numbers.

However, there is an issue that I can't understand and solve. I need to be able to **delete all numbers**, but it won't let me. I can delete only last two, and you can't delete colon.

Here is the current code:

```
var time = document.getElementsByClassName('time');
for (var i = 0; i < time.length; i++) {
    time[i].addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
        var reg = /[0-9]/;
        if (this.value.length == 2 && reg.test(this.value)) this.value = this.value + ":"; //Add colon if string length > 2 and string is a number 
        if (this.value.length > 5) this.value = this.value.substr(0, this.value.length - 1); //Delete the last digit if string length > 5
    });
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bubxm7pe/

Comment: I forked your jsfiddle example i guess it works as you wish https://jsfiddle.net/52n6ryuz/

Comment: You might want to look at a different way to implement this. If you quickly type the keys, you don't get `:`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add condition for backspace with `e.keyCode`

It works [here](https://jsfiddle.net/52n6ryuz/)

```
if (e.keyCode != 8)
{
      var reg = /[0-9]/;
      if (this.value.length == 2 && reg.test(this.value)) this.value = this.value + ":"; //Add colon if string length > 2 and string is a number 
      if (this.value.length > 5) this.value = this.value.substr(0, this.value.length - 1); //Delete the last digit if string length > 5           
}
```

Update: You can also restrict user with digits like following. It also works [here](https://jsfiddle.net/pmbpa2mf/)

```
//called when key is pressed in textbox
$(".time").keypress(function (e) {

    //if the letter is not digit then don't type anything
    if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
         return false;
    }
    else
    {
        var reg = /[0-9]/;
        if (this.value.length == 2 && reg.test(this.value)) this.value = this.value + ":"; //Add colon if string length > 2 and string is a number 
        if (this.value.length > 4) this.value = this.value.substr(0, this.value.length - 1); //Delete the last digit if string length > 5 

    }

});
```

Comment: @Plavookac your welcome :). I have also updated with "this.value = this.value.replace(/[^\d]/g, '')" to obtain restrict user with digit

Comment: oh, actually now it is removing : also when u added restriction, type all 4 numbers to see. :)

Comment: @Plavookac I found another solution for digit restriction, I will update in a couple of minutes

Answer (score 0):

Rather than check for `delete` or `backspace` you could check if the key pressed is a number:

```
if (keycode >= 48 && keycode <= 57) {
  if (this.value.length == 2 && reg.test(this.value)) this.value = this.value + ":"; //Add colon if string length > 2 and string is a number 
  if (this.value.length > 5) this.value = this.value.substr(0, this.value.length - 1); //Delete the last digit if string length > 5
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6jbaayqd/

Comment: hmm, this don't add colon anymore etc. But thanks for suggestion, will have in mind for future!

Answer (score 0):

As you are already *inclined* to use `regex`, then why not use it for formatting the time in the `input` field - see demo below:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('time')[0].addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  this.value = this.value
    .replace(/[^\d]/g, '') // allow only digits
    .replace(/^([\d]{4})\d+$/g, '$1') // restrict to 4 chars
    .replace(/\B(?=(\d{2})+(?!\d{1}))/g, ":"); // place the colon

});
```

```html
<input class="time" />
```

Comment: @Plavookac let me know your thoughts on this, thanks!